# Getting error to distribution profile creation

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Why am I getting the error below when I try to create a distribution profile for App store upload? Is it an error from the apple site, or an issue with my developer account? I have tried this in the safari browser.

[image]

Comment: Just wait for a while before you try. Try to do usual things like restarting your mac.

Comment: The error says it's not yours but an Apple error. I would try changing the browser, restarting the computer, clearing the browser cache and all of them together ;)